# Sleeping in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-threads, thread-synchronization

I have a task scheduled (@EnableSceduling) in a Spring Boot web service that repeats on a regular basis. When that task fires, it calls the registered object's Runnable/run method. In that run method, I need to do work and not exit that run method until the work is completed. The problem is that I have other threads doing other work that is needed by this run thread for its work. So in the run thread I have something like this:

```
@Component
public class DoWork implements Runnable {
    
    @override
    public void run() {
    
    // Setup clients.

    // Call services.
    Mono<String> response1 = client1.post();
    response1.subscribe(new MyResponseCallback(), new MyErrorCallback()); 
    
    Mono<String> response2 = client2.post();
    response2.subscribe(new MyResponseCallback(), new MyErrorCallback()); 

    Mono<String> responseX = clientX.post();
    responseX.subscribe(new MyResponseCallback(), new MyErrorCallback());
        
    while(callbacksWorkCompletedFlag == false) {
        
            Thread.sleep (1000);
        }

        // Do computation with callback responses.

        // After computation is completed, exit run method.
    }
}
```

---

```
public class MyResponseCallback implements Consumer<String> {
    
    @override
    public void accept (final Sting response) {
    
        // Do work with response.
    }
}
```

---

```
public class MyErrorCallback implements Consumer<Throwable> {
    
    @override
    public void accept (final Throwable error) {
    
        // Log error.
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to do this in Java/Spring boot?

Comment: Is it possible to have a more complete example, rather than trying to imagine it from the description? [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For example, at the moment I can't tell whether something like a Future, a Semaphore or a CyclicBarrier would be appropriate.

Comment: @scrhartley See updated code above? Does that help?

Comment: Do you mean [subscribe](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#subscribe-java.util.function.Consumer-java.util.function.Consumer-), rather then `onSubscribe`? Or am I looking in the wrong place?

Comment: @scrhartley Yes, you're right. I corrected it.

Comment: I'm currently trying to find something nicer that a [CountDownLatch](https://www.baeldung.com/java-countdown-latch)

Comment: @scrhartley How do you pass the CountdownLatch to the callbacks?

Comment: Just a thought: do you actually need the callbacks or can you instead use Mono.block() and then do everything with imperative code: `String response1 = client1.post().block();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example using `CompletableFuture`. It uses the third parameter for `Mono.subscribe` to let the future know when it's done.

```java
@Override
public void run() {
    Mono<String> response1 = client1.post();
    CompletableFuture<?> future1 = new CompletableFuture<>();
    response1.subscribe(
                new MyResponseCallback(), new MyErrorCallback(),
                () -> future1.complete(null));

    Mono<String> response2 = client2.post();
    CompletableFuture<?> future2 = new CompletableFuture<>();
    response2.subscribe(
                new MyResponseCallback(), new MyErrorCallback(),
                () -> future2.complete(null));

    Mono<String> responseX = clientX.post();
    CompletableFuture<?> futureX = new CompletableFuture<>();
    responseX.subscribe(
                new MyResponseCallback(), new MyErrorCallback(),
                () -> futureX.complete(null));
    
    CompletableFuture.allOf(future1, future2, futureX).join();
}
```

Here is a `CountDownLatch` example:

```java
@Override
public void run() {
    CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(3);

    Mono<String> response1 = client1.post();
    response1.subscribe(new MyResponseCallback(), new MyErrorCallback(), latch::countDown);

    Mono<String> response2 = client2.post();
    response2.subscribe(new MyResponseCallback(), new MyErrorCallback(), latch::countDown);

    Mono<String> responseX = clientX.post();
    responseX.subscribe(new MyResponseCallback(), new MyErrorCallback(), latch::countDown);
    
    try {
        latch.await();
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
}
```

Another `CompletableFuture` example:

```java
@Override
public void run() {
    List<CompletableFuture<?>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
    Supplier<Runnable> onDone = () -> {
        CompletableFuture<?> future = new CompletableFuture<>();
        futures.add(future);
        return () -> future.complete(null);
    };

    Mono<String> response1 = client1.post();
    response1.subscribe(new MyResponseCallback(), new MyErrorCallback(), onDone.get());

    Mono<String> response2 = client2.post();
    response2.subscribe(new MyResponseCallback(), new MyErrorCallback(), onDone.get());

    Mono<String> responseX = clientX.post();
    responseX.subscribe(new MyResponseCallback(), new MyErrorCallback(), onDone.get());

    CompletableFuture.allOf(futures.toArray(CompletableFuture[]::new)).join();
}
```

Are all the callbacks actually required?

```java
@Override
public void run() {
    // Make requests
    Mono<String> responseMono1 = client1.post();
    Mono<String> responseMono2 = client2.post();
    Mono<String> responseMonoX = clientX.post();
    try {
        // Wait for requests to complete
        String response1 = responseMono1.block();
        String response2 = responseMono2.block();
        String responseX = responseMonoX.block();

        ...
    }
    catch (RuntimeException e) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you swallowing `IterruptedException` instead of marking the thread as interrupted?

Comment: 1. InterruptedException doesn't tend to happen and even if you try hard, some part of the library chain won't handle it properly anyway 2. I didn't want to scare anyone off from the code. 3. There's not necessarily one way handle it e.g. maybe you would log it there-and-then, or maybe you rethrow after resetting the flag.

Comment: It will be great to provide some more information in your answer about thread interruption. If that code is running on a user-created thread, the interrupted exception can be swallowed according to user-specific interruption policy. By "user-created" I mean `new Thread(runnable).start()`. But I think that creating a new thread in which there will be a `CountdownLatch` or `CompletableFuture` is a kind of overhead. And if that code is running on a Spring thread you should not swallow the `InterruptedException` because you don't know Spring's interruption policy.

Comment: This example is trying to synchronize across threads and I introduced mechanisms for synchronizing across threads (ultimately, reactive is backed by a thread pool). I don't create any new threads, just use the existing language features (probably some CAS involved). I don't claim my handling of the InterruptedException is optimal. I will note that in Oracle's [Javadoc example](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) they either declare the exception (which we can't do here since it's a `Runnable`) or do the same as I have.

Comment: Updated answer to include using Mono.block()

Answer (score 1):

You are using reactive programming but forget about that and try to solve it imperativly. You don't need to sleep, utilize the features you have with Project Reactor instead.

You can use `zip` to combine the result of different `Mono` together, then `map` the result into what you need. No need to check a `boolean` use countdown latches etc.

```java
Mono<String> response1 = client1.post();   
Mono<String> response2 = client2.post();
Mono<String> responseX = clientX.post();
Mono<String> result = Mono
  .zip(response1, response2, response3)
  .map(//dosomething with the result of the 3 mono's)
  .subscribe();
```

What you are doing in your `Consumer` is a bit unclear, but you can probably use a `map` for that as well on each `Mono` (or if it is just to set a boolean you can remove them).